# Python Split Ignore Comma

Tags: python, split

In python I have a string that is inputted is like this

```
var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7
```

I'm using split to split the variables up into their own independent variables like this

```
stringone = var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7 = stringone.split(',')
```

Then I'm using them later on however sometimes var7 contains a comma or several commas (e.g. var7 may equal 'This, is, like'). This then messes up splitting them up as it appears that var7 is actually multiple variables.

How can I fix this so it sees var7 as one variable rather than mutlitples even when it finds one or more commas in the variable? If there was a way to only tell it to split by the first 6 commas I could imagine that would work but I am unsure how to do that.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are searching for is the [`maxsplit` parameter of `split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). This should do the trick:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7 = stringone.split(',', 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7 = stringone.split(',', 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is called [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

I would recommend creating a function that allows for an arbitrary number of `var`s by using the syntax described in the above link from the Python docs:

```
def var_consumer(*vars):
    """Do the same thing to all vars passed in."""
    pass

>>> consumed = var_consumer(stringone.split(','))
```

That way you don't have to guess how many vars are going to be passed to `var_consumer`. You can handle any number of them, even zero.